# GitLab SSH keys stopped working

Tags: git, github, ssh, private-key, gitlab

OK, I've stumbled on this topic many times, but this is the first time that none of the regular solutions worked.

I have a CentOS 6.4 server running [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/). It's been working great with 20+ users and 60+ projects, but about 5 hours ago, my main staging server was unable to connect to the GitLab machine for the first time using key authentication and it prompted for password. I regenerated the RSA key and added it to my deploy keys, but that failed as well.

Next, I tried to create a new user on the staging server, create a key for it, and add it to GitLab but it still fails.

Permissions:

```
drwxr-x---  22 root root 4.0K Oct 28 13:20 root
```

Inside root:

```
drwx------   2 root root     4096 Oct 28 11:49 .ssh
```

Inside .ssh:

```
-rw-------  1 root root  227 Oct 28 11:48 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 root root 1675 Oct 28 13:09 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 root root  398 Oct 28 13:09 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  413 Oct 28 11:49 known_hosts
```

When I try to connect to the git machine:

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.mygitlab.com [212.29.122.24] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'git.mygitlab.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-    mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No credentials cache found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-    mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@git.mygitlab.com's password:
```

When I add SSH keys through the web interface, they aren't added to `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I don't really know what to try next :(

Comment: Do you see your public key in the `git.mygitlab.com:~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: actually no ! i have 49 keys in the authorized keys files on the gitlab server, when i add additional keys they will not appear

Comment: So that is the issue right there. Is there any log in gitlab which would leave a clue?

Comment: none that i can find, i am able to add ssh keys to the gitlab web gui but they wont add to the authorized_keys

Comment: So a simple restart wouldn't help, then? (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4733)

Comment: unfortunately i restarted both machines.. didnt help.

Comment: Adn the troubleshooting page doesn't help either, I presume?

Comment: And this isn't an chown or chgrp issue, as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1345?

Comment: none of the above it an issue with Gitlab out of sync with authorized keys files. since im running an old version ( 4.0 ) im trying to upgrade version by version to see if its solved

Comment: I didn't know about GitLab version. I confirm an upgrade to 6.x would certainly be something to test and could solve the all issue.

Answer (score 5):

If keys that you add to GitLab aren't making it into `.ssh/authorized_keys`:

1. **Make sure that sidekiq is running**. Keys are added to gitlab-shell in a Sidekiq worker, so if Sidekiq is down or backlogged, they won't make it in. You can check this in the output of `ps -fu git` and by checking the "background jobs" tab on the admin page.
2. **Ensure that GitLab can execute gitlab-shell properly.** The Sidekiq worker adds keys by [exec'ing a `gitlab-shell` process](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/gitlab/backend/shell.rb#L124). In particular, this won't work if the `ssh_user` setting is incorrect in [gitlab.yml](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L32), or if gitlab-shell is installed to a location other than `~/gitlab-shell` for that user.
3. **Verify that the server's /home partition isn't full.** If the disk that the `authorized_keys` file is stored on fills up, key appends with fail! This one has gotten me a few times. Use `df -h /home` to see if you still have room.

Check your logs for error messages from gitlab-shell: depending on the problem, error messages could appear in unicorn's or sidekiq's logs.

Comment: Hi Ash,
You are 100% correct but as i said im using an old version of Gitlab ( 4.1) and i dont have gitlab-shell.. im trying to upgrade version by version untill it will be up to date

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that bit. Yeah, 4.1 was back in the gitolite days. If you pull the gitolite configuration repo directly, are your keys making into gitolite's settings? If not, there's a Rake task to resynchronize everything: `rake gitlab:gitolite:update_keys`

Comment: It's also possible that there's something amiss with your gitolite installation, like a missing or non-executable post-receive hook. Double-check your gitolite install: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

Answer (score 3):

Well, now i am under 5.1
i did it step by step
4.1 > 4.2 
4.2 > 4.3 
and finally everything is up and running.

Just for 4.1 users to know - > one of the developers added a bad key including the $#root... 
and this is what broke the sync.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem when I switched the GitLab server from HTTP to HTTPS.  Everything looked fine on the web server - logins, etc. were all working normally but git@gitlab SSH connections were failing.

After looking at #2 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19637026/2162639 (above) I discovered that I needed to modify the `gitlab_url` setting in `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yaml` to use `https://gitlab.server.fqdn` instead of `http://gitlab.server.fqdn`.  I changed that setting, restarted the gitlab service and everything was working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Had to delete all previous keys for the host. Problem is gitlab takes any older keys and if the match does not exist, it fails there. Your working key may be listed later in order and never picked.

Answer (score 0):

Since I spent a bunch of time troubleshooting this on Cent8, I wanted to post what the solution is. I attempted everything here, and still had an issue. My issue was the SELinux context on ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys.  You can check it with

```
ls -lZ ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and you will get something like

```
-rw-------. 1 git git unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 282 May  5 00:34 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

My file had the context **var_t** instead of **ssh_home_t** which was the problem. This is solved via

```
sudo chcon -t ssh_home_t ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Cheers!